# undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress', DSO missing from command line

Tags: 14.04, php, compiling

I'm trying to manually compile my php iconv extension so it uses libiconv instead of glibc. I downloaded libiconv, and configured with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` , `make` then `sudo make install`.

I found this instructions about manual compiling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743080/how-can-i-force-php-to-use-the-libiconv-version-of-iconv-instead-of-the-centos-in/4851065#4851065

I have a php version 5.6.10 and it was installed using phpbrew so I started at Step #3.

At step #5 (`make`), I encountered the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/standard/.libs/image.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Would you know how to fix this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20206371/2072269?

Comment: I wonder if your system doesn't have `zlib1g-dev`, and `./configure` isn't checking for it when it creates the makefile?

Comment: zlib1g-dev exists at `/usr/share/doc/zlib1g-dev`, I search in configure file but there's no zlib1g-dev @steeldriver

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by editing the `Makefile`, and adding `-lz` in `EXTRA_LIBS`.

1. Look for `Makefile` in the `php` directory.
2. Search for `EXTRA_LIBS`.
3. Add the `-lz` flag.

That links to the library that was missing. [`-lz` links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051202/how-does-gcc-ld-find-zlib-so) to [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/).

This solution is based on [kevinf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20206371/1038860) to [Strange linking error: DSO missing from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line) on Stack Overflow.